# Eject Flash Disk is currently used by the application in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, disk, removable-storage

I am trying to find a way from a c++ program to (remove, release, clear, etc...) the directory path that used to open a file from an external hard drive (flash disks) and cause the flash disk not to be able to eject with the classic error in windows (it is being used by an application)

The problem is that when you open a file by a c++ program and this file is on an external hard drive even if you close the file, it can't eject the external drive until you close the program that opened that file or the path to that external drive.

I tried to use `SetCurrentDirectory()` after each use of a file function in windows but it doesn't seem to work properly.

It still needs something to be released by the program so the external disk can be ejected.

Did anyone find a way to do this?

-------------- UDPATE

Michael Walz is correct.
FindClose(); for some cases 
CloseHandle(); for other cases
seems to be working fine by now as far as i tested.

Comment: How are you closing your file?

Comment: @UKMonkey i use many file function such _waccess(), CopyFile, etc etc, but i think the basic stuck comes from this option dialog that you can select a file https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx ... and thanks for the downvote ...

Comment: I could reproduce this with the software I'm maintaining which is written in MFC. When I open a file with that software, it creates several temporary files in the same directory as the as the opened file and keeps them open, when the file is closed (File-Close) then all open file handles are closed correctly. Scenario 1: I drag and drop a file from the Explorer window of the removable drive onto the Software, then I close the file with File-Close. Now I am able to eject the removable drive.

Comment: Scenario 2: I use the File-Open command in the software that uses the standard Windows "Open File dialog", and I browse to the removable drive and open the same file as in scenario 1. Then I close the file with File-Close. Now I'm not able to eject the removable drive until I quit the software. This is somewhat the same as what you experienced. Could you try scenario 2 with your software and report what happens? It looks like a Windows bug to me.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the suggestion, the problem is not only in my project, many companies software has the same errors, e.x. text viewers, readers, browswers, e.x. you open a script from ext.drive to the software and you open another tab with another script from local hdd, if you close the tab of the ext.drive script from your editor it will not be able to eject the drive, you will need to close the program and reopen it to free the resource as i guess.I want to avoid such behavior in my small project for ext.drives.

Comment: @Michael i tested many options and thats why i asked cause if there is a function or something that can free or close any path, link, file etc. from ext.drives after using them from a program.I cant file-close for example a loaded image cause it is opened in the program and then after using  it and closing it and not reading or viewing that image any more from the program even loading a new image from local hdd, the path that has been opened once from the progam to ext.drive is like is kept somewhere and i can`t find the correct way to free or release or close it from within the program.

Comment: @Vas your last comment is somewhat unclear, please [edit] your question and put that information there and makeing clear what does not work with your program by writing step by step what _you_ do, what your _program_ does etc. I understood that if you Open an image, then close it ,then you cannot open it again, but that part was really unclear. BTW I'm not aware of any function that could "close a file more" that closing it with `CloseHandle`.

Comment: @Michael sorry for the delay, to make it clear. I can reopen the image, i said that once you open, read, execute anything from an ext.drive even if after that you open, read, execute other file not from ext.drive the program keeps something open even after hours has passed from the ext.drive thouogh in the program nothing is used from the ext.drive anymore. In the OPENFILENAME structure that i guess that might have a problem causing this issue i cant close the handle cause i use NULL handle to open the default window. I am making some tests so i will upadte the question if found anything good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165155/discussion-between-michael-walz-and-vas).

Comment: @UKMonkey two hours may be annoying but it's still rather short in terms of amount of time to wait for a response. Looking at the timestamps, the OP was only able to respond 3 hours later, not 2, which (to me at least) isn't unreasonable at all.

Comment: @andlabs You'll note that the link says not only will I be happy to retract my down vote; but also that on asking a question it's not unreasonable to expect you to stay by the pc for the next 2-3 hours; not to answer in 2-3 hours.

Comment: @Michael thank you for your time. I will update if found anything new while testing it the next days

Comment: Huh?? What is `FileClose`??

Comment: @Michael i corrected the update in the question, it was FindClose() not FileClose.Thanks